# Equation solution(s) independent from variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, discrete-mathematics

Let the following eq:

$$D_1(x,y,z)x^n - D_2(x,y,z)y^n + D_3(x,y,z)z^n = \frac {h}{z}->[1]$$

for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ \ {0}

Where:

$$D_1(x,y,z)=-(1-x)(\frac{1-z}{z-x}+1)c_1 + (1-z)(\frac{1}{z-x}+\frac{1}{1-z})(c_2-c_3x)$$
$$D_2(x,y,z)=-(1-y)(\frac{1-z}{z-y}+1)c_1 + (1-z)(\frac{1}{z-y}+\frac{1}{1-z})(c_4-c_5y)$$
$$D_3(x,y,z)=(1-z)(\frac{1-x}{z-x}-\frac{1-y}{z-y})c_1 - (1-z)(x\frac{c_2z^{-1}-c_3}{z-x}+y\frac{c_4z^{-1}-c_5}{z-y})-\frac{c_6-zc_7}{z}$$

And $c_k$ and $h$ are known constants.

I would like to find the solutions where "N" doesn't affect the outcome in [1].
Given that a function $f(x,y,z,n) $ would be independent from $n$ if $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial n} = 0$ $D_1(x,y,z)x^nlnx - D_2(x,y,z)y^nlny + D_3(x,y,z)z^nlnz = 0$ may be the way to go (I think) but I haven't found a way to go around this. Also, the $\frac {h}{z}$ disappears, which I assume it would give a different solution?

I also tried a Taylor Series Expansion for [1]:

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{n^i}{i!} (D_1(x,y,z)(lnx)^i - D_2(x,y,z)(lnx)^i + D_3(x,y,z)(lnx)^i) = \frac {h}{z}$$

Which puts "n" apart from the other variables... but no more since there is now "i".

Please help, and thank you in advance.

Comment: What does D$_1$(x,y,z) mean?

Comment: @WilliamElliot $D_1, D_2 , D_3$ are functions acting as coefficients for $x^n,y^n,z^n$. I edited the question, adding their form for my specific problem